# Facebook likes button in winform application

Tags: facebook, winforms, facebook-like

i want to implement Facebook likes button in winform application. I am not able to find any document or example to solve my requirement. Is this Possible to LIKES page from winform application?

Answer (score 0):

My guess is you have to create a browser control on your winform application that shows a page that hosts your like button.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa752041%28v=vs.85%29.aspx

Comment: Yes that is true But my application is touch screen application. and that Likes Button open in New IE Browse.  I want to open that in WebBrowser Control

Comment: Check out this page. It shows how you can handle events that get triggered when the browser control wants to open a new window.

http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/13598/Extended-NET-2-0-WebBrowser-Control

Comment: Yes may be like this. But i am beginner and i m not able to understand this code. can u explain in simple code thanks for your replay

Comment: Yes your answer is correct But not correct for facebook like button in WebBrowser Control. are u aware with facebook like Button in winform application with WebBrowser Control ?